# Unix timestamp web service

Tags: web-services, unix-timestamp

Is there somewhere over the Internet a reliable web service that returns current Unix (UTC) timestamp?

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol

Comment: How can I query an NTP server through HTTP?

Comment: NTP is a very specific protocol. In short: you just enable it in your operating system and rely on local time.

Comment: It's a webApp, I don't have access to OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plausible workaround could be to use response headers that we get with HTTP responses. In some rare cases like mine, when you haven't direct access to web server and you can't create an API by yourself, you could send an XHR and fetch the response headers with

`response.getAllResponseHeaders()`

and then parse the `date` value inside returned string. Of course you have to trust the server date.
I know that is a rare (and maybe dumb) use case, but it could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can get it dependably using Python which could easily be ported to pretty much any language:

```py
from contextlib import closing
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import struct
import time

NTP_PACKET_FORMAT = "!12I"
NTP_DELTA = 2208988800  # 1970-01-01 00:00:00
NTP_QUERY = b'\x1b' + 47 * b'\0'  

def ntp_time(host="pool.ntp.org", port=123):
    with closing(socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)) as s:
        s.sendto(NTP_QUERY, (host, port))
        msg, address = s.recvfrom(1024)
    unpacked = struct.unpack(NTP_PACKET_FORMAT,
                   msg[0:struct.calcsize(NTP_PACKET_FORMAT)])
    return unpacked[10] + float(unpacked[11]) / 2**32 - NTP_DELTA
```

Where `ntp_time()` returns the current UTC Unix Timestamp including microseconds.

Comment: Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33436061/286807