# Script to set time correctly

Tags: python, date, time

I'm looking at making a quick python script that runs just after the system is booted. Basically, my CMOS battery is toast, and I can't get a new one at the moment. So I was thinking of making a script that checked the date and time online, and then set the system time via that. I've looked online for similar scripts, but I haven't seen any. Is this going to be possible in python? And how would I go about doing it? Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664295/ntp-client-in-python

Comment: Sorry, Im on Windows 7 Pro

Comment: And @Guy, how would I go about setting the system time once I have it from a server?

Comment: I believe Windows can do this automatically. See [How to Synchronize Windows Clock With Internet Time Server](http://www.guidingtech.com/3119/windows-clock-sync/)

Comment: @Kevin, Is there a way to make it sync more then once a week? On startup would be ideal, otherwise I could do "Every 2 minutes" or something.

Comment: Besides the GUI stuff, you can use `w32tm /resync` from a command prompt.  (Which means you can put it in a batch file and put the batch file in your Startup directory.)  See [this article](http://lifehacker.com/350074/sync-your-clock-to-internet-servers-from-the-command-prompt) and its accompanying comments for more information.  Also, you can of course Google for `w32tm`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rest webservice  (Python has json api but you can simply use 'requests' libs)

```
import requests
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth

r = requests.get('http://timeapi.org/utc/now.json?callback=myCallback', auth=('user', 'pass')

data = r.json()
```

and for the web service here you are (thanks to http://www.timeapi.org/ )  : 
http://timeapi.org/utc/now.json?callback=myCallback

Answer (score 0):

This python code will help you:

```
import os

os.environ['TZ'] = 'America/Montevideo'  # very important to set your time zone

os.system('ntpdate -s  south-america.pool.ntp.org')
print 'Time changed to: '
os.system('date')
```